How To Avoid Process Sleep of IIS
I implement service layer depend on Hangfire  service to run periodic function in web application  these service was stopped after some time if no one access the application URL
I try some configuration with app pool configurations in IIS but not work
is any way to keep service running even no access for URL
I change The configuration of idle time out to 0  , I expect no time out happened for the job working but all job stopped after some idle time

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a

Do the following to Keep the app to run continuously on IIS.
1.Configure the application pool
Open IIS Manager, right-click on the application pool which the application runs and select Advanced Settings. Then update the following values:

Set the .NET CLR Version to v4.0.
Set the Managed Pipeline Mode to Integrated
Set the Start Mode to Always Running.
Set the Idle Time-Out (minutes) to 0.

The Idle Time-Out value of 0 means your application never time out.
And setting the Start Mode to Always Running tells IIS to start a worker process for your application right away, without waiting for the initial request.

2.Configure the IIS site
Right-click on the site for the application, select Manage Website -> Advanced Settings, then set the Preload Enabled to true.


3.Configuration Editor
Go to the Configuration Editor on your app, and navigate to system.webServer/applicationInitialization.

doAppInitAfterRestart: True

Open up the Collection… ellipsis. On the next window, click Add and enter the following:
hostName: {URL host for your Hangfire application}
initializationPage: {path for your Hangfire dashboard, like /hangfire}


At last, you can learn more from Making ASP.NET Application Always Running
